# "in for a penny, in for a pound"

Tags: phrases, expressions

What does this mean? I'm English and I've never come across the meaning!

Comment: I'm slightly surprised, as this is a British expression. :)

Comment: exactly, i've never thought to ask

Comment: Fair enough. There are certainly many niche quotes and slang words I've heard but am not familiar with...

Comment: This might help: http://proverbhunter.com/proverb/in-for-a-dime-in-for-a-dollar/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[In for a penny, in for a pound](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/in+for+a+penny,+in+for+a+pound.html)** (idiom):

> "If something is worth doing then it is a case of in for a penny, in for a pound, which means that when gambling or taking a chance, you might as well go the whole way and take all the risks, not just some."

[Americanized form](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_for_a_dime,_in_for_a_dollar): "In for a dime, in for a dollar."

Comment: Is the American version common? I have only every heard the English version, even in Australia where we've had dollars since '66.

Comment: @dave No, you only hear the English one.

Comment: I am in the U.S., and I don't think I've ever heard the American version. I would understand it if it was used, though.

Answer (score 2):

It's an idiom for indicating that you might as well commit fully to the venture being referenced.

That's my take on it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I've also heard the related proverb (with a slightly different twist, though): “he that steals an egg will steal an ox”.

Answer (score 1):

What it actually means is related to crime: if you steal a penny and will go to jail for it, you may as well steal a pound. Either way you're *in* as in *in jail* (or *gaol*, depending on which side of the Atlantic will be prosecuting you). It obviously hails from a time when a penny and a pound were worth much more than they are today.

So if you've already violated a principle to *any* degree, it doesn't matter how far you go past the violation threshold, so you may as well derive maximum benefit.

Comment: And your evidence that this is necessarily to do with crime or violation? I think you are confusing it with "May as well be hanged for a sheep as a lamb".

Comment: @Colin Fine: Perhaps we're both right. The sense given in Wiktionary (see also http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in+for+a+penny,+in+for+a+pound) is "Originally with reference to the fact that if one owed a penny, one might as well owe a pound, as the penalties for non-payment were virtually identical in severity." This is from a time when debtors was tantamount to crime, and owing money could land you in the slammer. I've always heard it used in the "hanged for a sheep" context. But I'll admit the distinction may be blurred.

Comment: Yes, but you've added the "in" = "in jail" to this, which I believe is unwarranted.

Comment: @Colin Fine: The penalties spoken of above involving being in jail, so I believe it *is* warranted.

Comment: Not in what you've quoted, they don't. To me "in for a penny" is the same kind of "in" as "Right, we're going to play poker/go for a drive/have dinner/rob a bank. Who's in?", and I want evidence before I accept that it is anything to do with jail.

Comment: @Colin Fine: If the history of debtors' prisons and the statement to the effect that "the penalties for non-payment were virtually identical in severity" don't sway you, I am content for you to remain unconvinced.